# warning: Selected architecture i8086 is not compatible with reported target architecture i386:x86-64

Tags: gdb, qemu

When I started "qemu-system-x86_64 -S -s" and used gdb attach to that vm, everything is worked as I expected, but when I issued the command "set architecture i8086", it told me,

> warning: Selected architecture i8086 is not compatible with reported target architecture i386:x86-64
> warning: A handler for the OS ABI "GNU/Linux" is not built into this configuration
> of GDB.  Attempting to continue with the default i8086 settings.
> Architecture `i8086' not recognized.
> The target architecture is set automatically (currently i386:x86-64)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following blog that's worked for my problem, but you need to use qemu-system-i386 32bit version of qemu.

https://astralvx.com/debugging-16-bit-in-qemu-with-gdb-on-windows/